# Azure Mysql keep high cpu usage and I cannot tune it down

Tags: mysql, asp.net, multithreading

I have an asp.net application which use Azure Mysql as database server. In my application have some threading which will query mysql database. It always caused the Azure Mysql database server CPU usage up to 99%. Then I try to edit the server parameters of Azure MySQL. I tuned as follows:

```
   innondb_buffer_pool_size : from 16106127360 bytes to 134217728 bytes.
   innodb_thread_concurrency: from 0 to 33
   wait_timeout: from 120 to 30
   interactive_timeout: from 28800 to 30
```

But it is not useful. When I run the application. The CPU usage of Azure MySQL still use 99%. The above tunning seems not useful. What tuning should I do to lower the CPU usage of Azure MySQL?

Comment: enable slow_log the internal tables that are converted from a memory table to a disk based table for [query processing](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/internal-temporary-tables.html) can cause a good amount off cpu usage as the data needs to go from ram to disk... Also does `INSERT  ... SELECT ...` syntax which also can cause a good amount off cpu usage ...

Comment: when you enable slow_log you can start checking your queries, by running `EXPLAIN` on them and look for "using temporary" in the output  ...

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
RAM size, # cores of your MySQL Host server 
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @WilsonHauck Thanks. The info is in https://pastebin.com/CEE25iLa

Comment: Thanks for posting your data.

Comment: dup of https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/250053/mysql-keep-high-cpu-usage-and-i-cannot-tune-it-down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 and (p_objectName is null
   OR p_objectName = ''
   or l.ObjectName = p_objectName)
```

is an inefficient way to do things.  It prevents the usage of indexes.

First, decide between

- NULL
- ''
- always set

then get rid of the options you don't need.  Change the column definition (`NOT NULL` or whatever) and simplify the query.

This has the issues mentioned above, plus the inefficiency of `FIND_IN_SET()`.

```
and (p_ids is null
  OR p_ids = ''
  or FIND_IN_SET(l.id, p_ids))
```

Re-think how to look in sets of things.

And there is another Q&A hassling you over

```
           (p_q1 is null or u.Q1 = p_q1)
        or (p_q2 is null or u.Q2 = p_q2)
        or (p_q3 is null or u.Q3 = p_q3)
        or (p_q4 is null or u.Q4 = p_q4)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Observations:**

- Version: 5.7.22-log
- 16 GB of RAM
- Uptime = 16:50:57; some GLOBAL STATUS values may not be meaningful yet.
- You are running on Windows.
- Running 64-bit version
- You appear to be running entirely (or mostly) InnoDB.

**The More Important Issues:**

`tmp_table_size` should be no more than 1% of RAM.  Otherwise, a burst of complex queries *may* lead to swapping, which is terrible for performance.

Several metrics indicate the lack of adequate indexes.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog for finding those queries.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql for devising indexes for them.

`innodb_buffer_pool_size` should be set to about 70% of *available* RAM -- 10G.  However, since the buffer_pool is mostly empty, raising the value will not be useful.  On the other hand, if your data is likely to grow, keep this setting in mind.

If using SSDs, `innodb_flush_neighbors = 0`

Do you use BEGIN...COMMIT?  Or autocommit=ON?

60 Threads_running?  They are probably stumbling over each other.  (1) speed up the queries, (2) throttle at the client.

`myisam_sort_buffer_size` -- dangerously large; change to 300M

Turn off the General Log when not using it -- It tend to fill up disk in a big hurry.

**Details and other observations:**

`( innodb_buffer_pool_size / _ram ) = 2048M / 16384M = 12.5%` -- % of RAM used for InnoDB buffer_pool

`( innodb_lru_scan_depth * innodb_page_cleaners ) = 1,024 * 4 = 4,096` -- Amount of work for page cleaners every second.
-- "InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took ..." may be fixable by lowering lru_scan_depth: Consider 1000 / innodb_page_cleaners (now 4)

`( innodb_page_cleaners / innodb_buffer_pool_instances ) = 4 / 8 = 0.5` -- innodb_page_cleaners
-- Recommend setting innodb_page_cleaners (now 4) to innodb_buffer_pool_instances (now 8)

`( innodb_lru_scan_depth ) = 1,024`
-- "InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took ..." may be fixed by lowering lru_scan_depth

`( Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free * 16384 / innodb_buffer_pool_size ) = 120,208 * 16384 / 2048M = 91.7%` -- buffer pool free
-- buffer_pool_size is bigger than working set; could decrease it

`( Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free / Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total ) = 120,208 / 131072 = 91.7%` -- Pct of buffer_pool currently not in use
-- innodb_buffer_pool_size (now 2147483648) is bigger than necessary?

`( Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data / innodb_buffer_pool_size ) = 175,161,344 / 2048M = 8.2%` -- Percent of buffer pool taken up by data
-- A small percent *may* indicate that the buffer_pool is unnecessarily big.

`( Uptime / 60 * innodb_log_file_size / Innodb_os_log_written ) = 60,657 / 60 * 48M / 10239488 = 4,969` -- Minutes between InnoDB log rotations Beginning with 5.6.8, this can be changed dynamically; be sure to also change my.cnf.
-- (The recommendation of 60 minutes between rotations is somewhat arbitrary.) Adjust innodb_log_file_size (now 50331648). (Cannot change in AWS.)

`( innodb_flush_method ) = innodb_flush_method =` -- How InnoDB should ask the OS to write blocks. Suggest O_DIRECT or O_ALL_DIRECT (Percona) to avoid double buffering. (At least for Unix.) See chrischandler for caveat about O_ALL_DIRECT

`( innodb_flush_neighbors ) = 1` -- A minor optimization when writing blocks to disk.
-- Use 0 for SSD drives; 1 for HDD.

`( innodb_io_capacity ) = 200` -- I/O ops per second capable on disk . 100 for slow drives; 200 for spinning drives; 1000-2000 for SSDs; multiply by RAID factor.

`( innodb_print_all_deadlocks ) = innodb_print_all_deadlocks = OFF` -- Whether to log all Deadlocks.
-- If you are plagued with Deadlocks, turn this on. Caution: If you have lots of deadlocks, this may write a lot to disk.

`( join_buffer_size / _ram ) = 262,144 / 16384M = 0.00%` -- 0-N per thread. May speed up JOINs (better to fix queries/indexes) (all engines) Used for index scan, range index scan, full table scan, each full JOIN, etc.
-- If large, decrease join_buffer_size (now 262144) to avoid memory pressure. Suggest less than 1% of RAM. If small, increase to 0.01% of RAM to improve some queries.

`( myisam_sort_buffer_size / _ram ) = 4096M / 16384M = 25.0%` -- Used for ALTER, CREATE INDEX, OPTIMIZE, LOAD DATA; set when you need it. Also for MyISAM's REPAIR TABLE.
-- Decrease myisam_sort_buffer_size (now 4294967296) to keep from blowing out RAM.

`( character_set_server ) = character_set_server = utf8`
-- Charset problems may be helped by setting character_set_server (now utf8) to utf8mb4. That is the future default.

`( net_buffer_length / max_allowed_packet ) = 16,384 / 10M = 0.16%`

`( local_infile ) = local_infile = ON`
-- local_infile (now ON) = ON is a potential security issue

`( tmp_table_size ) = 2048M` -- Limit on size of *MEMORY* temp tables used to support a SELECT
-- Decrease tmp_table_size (now 2147483648) to avoid running out of RAM. Perhaps no more than 64M.

`( Handler_read_rnd_next / Com_select ) = 7,170,628,371 / 95062 = 75,431` -- Avg rows scanned per SELECT. (approx)
-- Consider raising read_buffer_size (now 65536)

`( (Com_insert + Com_update + Com_delete + Com_replace) / Com_commit ) = (14560 + 0 + 33 + 0) / 0 = INF` -- Statements per Commit (assuming all InnoDB)
-- Low: Might help to group queries together in transactions; High: long transactions strain various things.

`( Select_full_join / Com_select ) = 55,648 / 95062 = 58.5%` -- % of selects that are indexless join
-- Add suitable index(es) to tables used in JOINs.

`( Select_scan ) = 247,281 / 60657 = 4.1 /sec` -- full table scans
-- Add indexes / optimize queries (unless they are tiny tables)

`( Select_scan / Com_select ) = 247,281 / 95062 = 260.1%` -- % of selects doing full table scan. (May be fooled by Stored Routines.)
-- Add indexes / optimize queries

`( slow_query_log ) = slow_query_log = OFF` -- Whether to log slow queries. (5.1.12)

`( Com_change_db / Connections ) = 39,710 / 168 = 236` -- Database switches per connection
-- (minor) Consider using "db.table" syntax

`( Threads_running - 1 ) = 61 - 1 = 60` -- Active threads (concurrency when data collected)
-- Optimize queries and/or schema

`( Threads_created / Connections ) = 149 / 168 = 88.7%` -- Rapidity of process creation
-- Increase thread_cache_size (now 10) (non-Windows)

`( Threads_running / thread_cache_size ) = 61 / 10 = 6.1` -- Threads: current / cached (Not relevant when using thread pooling)
-- Optimize queries

You have the Query Cache half-off. You should set both query_cache_type = OFF and query_cache_size = 0 . There is (according to a rumor) a 'bug' in the QC code that leaves some code on unless you turn off both of those settings.

**Abnormally small:**

```
10 * read_buffer_size = 0.6MB
Innodb_buffer_pool_reads * innodb_page_size / innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2.7%
Innodb_rows_updated = 0
Key_reads+Key_writes + Innodb_pages_read+Innodb_pages_written+Innodb_dblwr_writes+Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed = 0.41 /sec
```

**Abnormally large:**

```
Com_create_table = 64 /HR
Com_drop_table = 0.035 /sec
Com_show_create_proc = 4.6 /HR
Com_show_status = 1.2 /sec
Handler_read_rnd_next / Handler_read_rnd = 36,149
Innodb_log_writes / Innodb_log_write_requests = 152.3%
Innodb_os_log_pending_writes = 1
Sort_range = 88 /sec
Threads_running = 61
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 4096MB
net_read_timeout = 999,999
net_write_timeout = 999,999
```

**Abnormal strings:**

```
ft_boolean_syntax = + -><()~*:&
general_log = ON
have_crypt = NO
innodb_fast_shutdown = 1
log_syslog = ON
lower_case_file_system = ON
lower_case_table_names = 1
optimizer_trace = enabled=off,one_line=off
optimizer_trace_features = greedy_search=on, range_optimizer=on, dynamic_range=on, repeated_subselect=on
session_track_system_variables = time_zone, autocommit, character_set_client, character_set_results, character_set_connection
slave_rows_search_algorithms = TABLE_SCAN,INDEX_SCAN
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
innodb_thread_concurrency=0  # from 33 to allow OS management of limit
thread_cache_size=100  # from 10 per v7 refman CAP recommended will reduce threads_create count
innodb_buffer_pool_size=8G  # from 2G for half of your RAM max
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 1024 to conserve 90% CPU cycles used for function
```

Observation: 
A) threads_running count of 61 for a CPU with only 8 cores causes many delays
B) threads_connected count of 73 makes me suspect there is no CLOSE() function requested  when the client processing has been completed.

Disclaimer: I am the content author of website mentioned in my profile, Network profile where we have FREE Utility Scripts to assist with performance tuning and contact info.  Please try to Skype to me.

Comment: @want_to_be_calm Have you applied these suggestions?  Please post comment on better/worse performance from your perspective.

Comment: @want_to_be_calm  Is your system better today than a few weeks ago?  If so, please upvote any helpful tips and possibly Accept any Answer(s) that helped you.  With no feedback, we have no idea of your outcome.